# What type of feed is most appropriate for a feed in a user profile that shows all of the posts that he or she has voted on?

Tags: getstream-io

I am writing an app where users can make posts.

Each post has a vote button. In the user's profile page, I would like to have a feed that shows all posts that were voted on by the user.

In this case, should I create a Flat Feed named "voted"? Then, would I add an activity to "voted" each time a user clicks on the vote button of a post? Is this best way?

I am new to the getstream API so any feedback to enhance my understanding of the API and its possibilities would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That would work!

Comment: @StephenHodgetts Thanks. But I believe that the approach that I had described is not the way. In doing some additional reading, it seems that the "vote" in my case would be best represented as a "reaction" in your API. Correct? If so, the write up on reactions in your docs seems to be a good starting point: [Reactions](https://getstream.io/docs/reactions_introduction/?language=js)

Comment: @StephenHodgetts Reactions works for my use case, so I will be closing this question. Thanks.

Comment: Great, good luck with your implementation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that "vote" action in my case would be best represented as a "reaction" in the getstream API. So, the write up on reactions in the docs seems to be a good starting point: [Reactions](https://getstream.io/docs/reactions_introduction/?language=js)